# How to map SAML assertion attribute values onto roles in SP with PicketLink?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, picketlink

We're implementing a SAML2-Based SSO solution and use PicketLink on the SP side.

On the IDP side we have a different implementation which is configured to output the multivalued `memberOf` attribute (these are actually LDAP/AD-group memberships. So we get basically get something like this in the assertion:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ... >
    ...
    <saml:Assertion ...>
        ...
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute FriendlyName="Role" Name="Role">
                <saml:AttributeValue>authenticated</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute FriendlyName="memberOf" Name="memberOf">
                <saml:AttributeValue>CN=ga-A-102213-...</saml:AttributeValue>
                <saml:AttributeValue>CN=g-z-MeetingPlace,...</saml:AttributeValue>
                <saml:AttributeValue>CN=g-z-Serviceportal,...</saml:AttributeValue>
                <saml:AttributeValue>CN=g-z-BCM...</saml:AttributeValue>
                ...
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
        ...
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

**My question is, how could I configure PicketLink/JBoss to map these `memberOf` values onto specific roles in the application/SP?**

For instance that `CN=g-z-MeetingPlace,...` should be mapped to `ROLE_MEETING` or `CN=g-z-BCM...` should be mapped onto `ROLE_BCM`. We could probably write a login module to do that, but for me it seems to be a very standard task. However I did not manage to find a configurative solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like we've figured it out.

What we needed was [`org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RoleMappingLoginModule`](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RoleMappingLoginModule):

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RoleMappingLoginModule"
  flag="optional"> 
  <module-option name="rolesProperties">roles.properties</module-option>
</login-module>
```

Mapping between AD group names and internal application roles is configured in the `roles.properties` file:

```
CN\=ga-A-102213-...=SomeInternalRole
```